# Dietary Supplement data

Tags: openfda

Does this data contain recall data (or any data) on dietary supplements for humans or dietary supplements for animals (which is handled by the Veterinary Drug department)?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion of data to include in the openFDA API. What kind of information would be most useful? Recall enforcement reports only, or other kinds of data?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an official answer (*I am just a community member passionate about the project*)

### Dietary Supplements - YES

If you search for a recent dietary supplement report from http://www.fda.gov/ForConsumers/ConsumerUpdates/ucm153239.htm on the `https://api.fda.gov/drug/enforcement.json` API endpoint, you do get results. Note this is the drug enforcement report endpoint, not the food enforcement report endpoint.

For example: `https://api.fda.gov/drug/enforcement.json?search=bee%20pollen&limit=1` matches the most recent update from the aforementioned FDA link (http://www.fda.gov/ForConsumers/ConsumerUpdates/ucm401676.htm).

---

### Veterinary Drugs - NO

Animal and veterinary recalls and market withdrawals appear to be listed at http://www.fda.gov/AnimalVeterinary/SafetyHealth/RecallsWithdrawals/default.htm. When I do a search on the food and drug enforcement report API endpoints, I don't get any results.

When I do a search on the device enforcement report endpoint, I get *some* results when I search  keywords for recent animal drug recalls... however they have older dates so they must be previous ones. Bottom line: doesn't seem like recent animal/veterinary drug recalls are in any openFDA at this time.